# Display Template and Item Template not showing in Content Search Web Part

Tags: web-part, csom, publishing-site, provider-hosted-app, display-template

I am facing a weird issue. When I'm uploading custom Display Template JS file and custom Item Template JS file using an Add-In, for some reason it is not showing in the webpart properties. But when I do the same thing manually, it comes in thr dropdowns for Display and Item properties of Content Search Web Part.

I have checked all the properties of uploaded JS files, Check-Out and Check-in, and Publishing the files as well. Still of no use. My Site is a Publishing Site.

Can anyone guide me towards the solution?

Comment: Try uploading the html files instead. SP should auto-generate those JS files for you (publishing feature needs to be turned on)

Comment: Be sure to publish, too, otherwise the new template won't appear in the dropdown.